Sci-fi book in which the main character went to a space academy and found some secret powerful gloves
When I was in 6th or 7th grade (around 2016-2017), I read this book about a main character (MC) whose mom was part of a space academy and the MC went to that academy to learn. The aliens and humans in this book use gloves to fight and fly, and the main character finds some secret powerful gloves while he is in another world. I forgot most of the plot after that, but the MC can't take off the gloves or it hurts to take them off because they are fused to his hands. The gloves were purple, I think.
